# Rails - initiate RSS feed from within application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss

I am following the RailsCasts episode about feed parsing.

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing
```

My model is call `Article`. I want to start the RSS feed when the Rails application is initialized, so I make the following call:

```
Article.update_from_feed("http://feeds.feedburner.com/CoinDesk")
```

In `config/application.rb`

However, when I start the server I get a database error at this line saying that the `Article` table does not exist yet.

Where should I place this code instead such that I get `Article` objects at initialisation?

Comment: Have you run `rake db:migrate` yet?

Comment: That was the problem. I hadn't.